# A button that apears on a day and time

Tags: flutter, dart

Is it posibe to make a button that apears on Sunday at 11AM? I know I can use `setVisibility()` but I don't know how to call out on a specific time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can resolve this with a DateTime and a ternary expression.

```dart
DateTime.now().weekday == 7 && DateTime.now().hour == 11 ?
            ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text("Im only here on Sundays at 11AM to 11AM59")) 
            : Container(),
```

Comment: You might also want a `Timer` that would call `setState()` in case the clock hits the desired time while the screen is open.

Comment: @Skullz, how can I incorporate that to the example?

Comment: @Lucas simply define a `Timer` object in `initState` (use `Timer.periodic(duration, callback)` constructor) and for the call back you could do something like `if (desiredTimeReached) setState((){})`. Don't forget to cancel the timer in `dispose`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a timer with  duration of (diff(datetime.now - target time)) on the timer function  call the set Visibility  method